# Default AES length for java crypto cipher

Tags: java, scala, encryption, aes, password-encryption

I have a query about the default AES key length and symmetric/asymmetric mode in javax.crypto.Cipher library.

I created a cipher as follows (I am in Java8 & Scala 2.12.x):

```
val mycipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
mycipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, givemeKey(), givemeIV())

private def givemeKey(keyPass: Option[String] = None) = {
    new SecretKeySpec(new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer('XxXxXxYyYyYXxZzZz-5z3y**\n'), "AES")
}

private def givemeIV() = {
    val myuuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString.split("-").mkString("").getBytes()
    val mybyteIV = new Array[Byte](16)
    System.arraycopy(myuuid, 0, mybyteIV, 0, 16)
    val returnIV = new IvParameterSpec(mybyteIV)
    returnIV
}
```

I did look into documentations of Cipher package. Still I have two questions which I can not able to figure out, hence reaching out to you:

1. What is the length of AES here? AES-256 or something else?
2. What is the 'type' (symmetric or asymmetric). I think it's symmetric -- just want to confirm.

Comment: It’s AES, what do you think the type is?

Comment: AES is symmetric, the key length is 16 = AES-128 accoding the answer of @Stephen C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) for `javax.crypto.Cipher`, that string (`"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"`) gives you an AES cipher algorithm.

There isn't a default key length.  (But there is a guarantee that every standard Java SE platform *supports* AES keys of 128 bits.  Some Java SE platforms support other AES key lengths (192 & 256) as well.)

The actual key length is not part of the algorithm name / `Cipher` object.  It will depend on whatever key that `givemeKey` is returning.   However in your example the base64 encoded key string is 24 characters long so that means it could not possibly be a 265 bit key.

(Do the math. 6 bits per character x 24 characters == 144 bits max.  So assuming that some of those bits are "envelope" or "padding", that looks like it would be an 128 bit key.)

AES is a symmetric-key algorithm; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).

Comment: You are correct.  I misread what the javadoc was saying.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it. Thanks @Stephen C.